# Can i store application data using bloc

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used redux in react-native and so when moving flutter i am learning bloc.
I know about the working of bloc in basic like how to handle API call and manage state of the widget in flutter.Now i want to know if i can store application of the whole data like list of products in cart with bloc.Something like this.

```
void main() => runApp(
    BlocProvider<ApplicationBloc>(
      bloc: ApplicationBloc(),
      child: MyApp(),
    )
);
```

Other screen will have there own bloc but this application bloc will store data related to whole app.
Is this correct or not or to store application data like user data do i have to store in shared preferences?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to save data in shared preferences as you said and emit a corresponding bloc event to see if data is stored in shared preferences.

Another way is to use the hydrated bloc package, which allows you to automatically save the state of a bloc, and upon restart of the app, the hydrated bloc automatically restores it's state which was saved. This is for example useful if you want to save if the user enabled black theme and thus to restore the app with the black theme.

You can read further about hydrated bloc here: [hydrated bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc)

Comment: Can i juat store suppose list of product in application bloc without shared prefernces

Comment: Sure as a variable, but it will be deleted when you restart your app.
There are also other storage options like Hive, when you don't want to use shared preferences. Even tough, using shared preferences is quite easy as you only have to do `sharedPreferences.setString(stringKey, stringData);` , where stringKey is used to retrieve the stored stringData, with `sharedPreferences.getString(stringKey);`